# ios UITableView -> UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone leaves a line of one pixel height blank

Tags: ios, uitableview, separator

I want to omit the separation line between two tableview cells. But instead of no separator I get a separation line of height 1 pixel that is simply left blank or better said completly transparent.

How can I tell the uitableview how to attach the next cell directly to the cell above (without any gap)?

Comment: I too have just noticed I'm getting this.
I used  
[m_tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]]; which got rid of the line but still see that separation line like you say.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, found the answer for mine and sharing it just incase it helps others.

I set all my cells up procedurally so I turned off the separator via

`m_tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f]]`

next I set the separator style via

```
m_tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

although I have to admit that didn't seem to do anything and this might be a redherring.

For me I found that cellForRowAtIndexPath was called to configure the cell and I had to extend my background image by 1 pixel in height to get rid of the line (I am using a stretchable image for this too which might also be lending itself to the bizarre +1 requirement).  I'm not a fan of arbitary +1's but this seemed to do the trick...

```
frameBackground.size.height += 1;
```

so whilst not endorsing a +1 the above steps have worked for my listview and now no longer have a separator.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had my header set to 1, removing this fixed my issue (I had additional 1 pixel in the odd cell separator) I changed to 0 and life seems better

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get rid of the separator so I finally decided to write my own tableview on top of UIScrollView.  And the "separator" was still there!  It turns out there is a bug in UILabel that will sometimes cause it to draw a thin line along the top edge if you set a background color.  The fix is to set the background on the layer:  label.layer.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;